# onkeydown event variable breaking the EventListener code

Tags: javascript, dom, event-handling, dom-events

I have the following Javascript code:

```
var field = document.createElement("INPUT");
field.type = "text";
field.addEventListener("blur", function() {
  // stuff that works
  (e ? e : window.event).stopPropagation();
  return false;
};
field.addEventListener("keydown", function() {
  alert("1");
  if (e) {
    alert("2");
  } else {
    alert("3");
    e = window.event;
  }
  alert("4");
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    this.blur();
  }
  return true;
}
```

The input field is not inside a form. Pressing enter or going out of focus is meant to submit the field value to the server (existing code I can't change). The `onblur` event works but the `onkeydown` event is not. `alert("1")` is executed exactly but that's all. Nothing else happened.

I have tried experimenting around and my guess is that the mere existence of `e` is breaking the code. I have no idea how: don't all event listeners pass an `e` parameter to the function being called? What's going on here? How can I resolve this?

No jQuery please, it's not available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not accepting an `e` parameter.

In your working event, you're using `e` if it exists (which it wont), or falling back to `window.event` if it doesn't:

```
(e ? e : window.event)
```

Similar checks do not exist in the broken event listener.

Make sure you accept a parameter named `e`:

```
field.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
```

... and it will be available in your code.